# How to make lines of text go away in python

Tags: python, passwords

So I have this code that needs a password.

```
password = input('Enter your password: ')
if password == 'yellow':
    print('You have made it inside the computer')
```

But I want to make it so that when I press enter, the line that says "Enter your password: yellow" will go away. I looked this up and visited lots of websites, but none of them answered my question. At the very least, I want to know how to make it so that when I type "yellow" it will appear as "******" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need external libraries for that. See [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getpass-and-getuser-in-python-password-without-echo/)

Ex.

```
import getpass 
  
p = getpass.getpass(prompt='Your favorite flower? ') 
  
if p.lower() == 'rose': 
    print('Welcome..!!!') 
else: 
    print('The answer entered by you is incorrect..!!!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the getpass module.

```
import getpass 

password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password: ')
if password == 'yellow':
    print('You have made it inside the computer')
```